# replacing header text on jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to replace text in a h3 tag based on jQuery click event. However, my code is not working and if I put an alert statement inside the click event, I can see that I am reacting inside the function but not able to execute text() call.

Header HTML markup

```
<div class="section margin-top-50">
    <h3 id="page_header" class="section-height"><?php echo $this->translate('Text_1'); ?></h3>
</div>
```

Menu HTML markup (where I am defining the click events)

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-layout-sidebar nav-stacked">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#mood-graph" data-toggle="tab">
            <?php echo $this->translate('Text_1') ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#quick-mood-stats" data-toggle="tab">
            <?php echo $this->translate('Text_2') ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#mood-rating" data-toggle="tab">
            <?php echo $this->translate('Text_3') ?>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#myTab li:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
        alert('clicked 1');
        $("#page_header h3").text("<?php echo $this->translate('Text_1'); ?>");
    });
    $("ul#myTab li:nth-child(2)").click(function() {
        alert('clicked 2');
        $("#page_header h3").text("<?php echo $this->translate('Text_2'); ?>");
    });
    $("ul#myTab li:nth-child(3)").click(function() {
        alert('clicked 3');
        $("#page_header h3").text("<?php echo $this->translate('Text_3'); ?>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Just so you know, the PHP is executed before the client-sided scripts.

Comment: as the answer below tells you you have given(<h3>) --  (<h3 id="page_header") an id. so once you have an id then you only need ($("#page_header")) to whatever with <h3>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this -

```
$("#page_header h3")
```

to this -

```
$("#page_header")
```

Your first selector is looking for h3's that are children of the page_header. They are actually one in the same and you only need to use the ID to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call PHP from JavaScript. In order to accomplish something like that, you'd need AJAX, but I don't think it's necessary for what I think you're trying to do.

Add a class 'toggleHeader' to each anchor. Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.toggleHeader').on('click', function() {
        $('#page_header').html( $(this).html() );
    });
});
```

No need to break it up by each anchor when you can just grab the contents of the anchor you clicked